# Luggage storage around the world. Is there an online resource to easily find it?

Tags: luggage, online-resources

I am going to travel, and I am planning on doing some day trips where I might sleep in the destination (or hike for a couple of days).
Either way I don't want to carry all my luggage with me. Only the essentials.

I am looking for online services that show places where I can store luggage or even better also allow to book luggage storage in advance. Kind of an uber for luggage storage.

Is there any website that stands out from the croud, in terms of global coverage, diversity of locations and prices?

Note1: I would prefer global coverage in such service, but since sometimes there are better local alternatives, I would like to add that I will be travelling through Spain, Portugal and Morocco.

Note2: I might also do Turkey and Thailand in future occasions, but not sure if I am stretching the scope of my question.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such resource. Your best shot are airports, train stations and hotels (you stay with). Availability, prices and terms vary wildly. So far I always had to do very specific research for a specific location. Even then, the info isn't readily available. For hotels, you typically have to call them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a *public* resource for this, but several platforms have tried, or are trying, to create a market for this kind of information. Some allow you to sign up as a 'host' for storing people's luggage. The slogan "The AIRBNB of luggage" has been used for this.

[This article](https://www.valisemag.com/luggage-storage-apps/) compares a few.

They are:

1. nannybag.com
2. radicalstorage.com
3. usebounce.com
4. stasher.com
5. luggagehero.com
6. vertoe.com
7. airkeep.me
8. getstoreme.com
9. bagsaway.com

[Here](https://travelislife.org/best-luggage-storage-apps/)'s another article that compares a few.

Answer (score 7):

I'm unaware of a global resource which completely answers this question worldwide, but there are some strategies you can try:

- If you are staying in a hotel, ask there. Especially if you plan to return to the same hotel after your side trip, they will often say yes. This goes especially if you are in a region where tourists commonly take multiday hikes and the desire to leave luggage is common.
- Many hotels will let non-guests store their luggage for a few dollars, either as an official policy or as an unofficial practice if you ask nicely and tip the person who helps you, but obviously this can not be guaranteed in all circumstances.
- Many large train stations or other transportation hubs have luggage storage facilities, usually for a fee, and information about these is often (though not always!) available online.
- If you are hiking with a tour operator or similar, they may allow you to store your luggage in their office or be in a position to offer another suggestion.
- There are companies like [Luggagehero and its competitors](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/03/02/travel/getaway-luggage-storage.html) which make websites or apps and partner with local business to let you store your luggage for a fee. I have never tried any of these services myself but frequently see them advertised in large cities.
- If all else fails, try searching the Internet for "left luggage [cityname]" or similar; you may be able to find some businesses which offer this service, or discussion forums where other travelers have experienced and hopefully solved this issue in the past.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is quite comprehensive in alternative strategies and definitely a plus.  Some of these I knew, but nonetheless good to have. The reason for looking for luggage storage in advance is because I want my chances to be covered. I usually travel on tight time frames and prefer to spend time enjoying the destination rather than taking care of things I could have prepared.